# KeyCharacterMap to use from code only

Tags: android, input

I need to insert a special character into my Android app that is not included in any the existing KeyCharacterMap files. Generating key events is the only way I see to get any active control without knowing which one.

To load this map in order to generate the KeyEvent from I have to specify the map's id but this ID comes from an InputDevice and there is no such device for my newly generated kcm file.

What is the best way to either use this keymap without an existing inputdevice or fake the inputdevice?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can generate special key with this solution :

```
char[] szRes = szStringText.toCharArray(); // Convert String to Char arra

KeyCharacterMap CharMap;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) // My soft runs until API 5
  CharMap = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD);
else
  CharMap = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.ALPHA);

KeyEvent[] events = CharMap.getEvents(szRes);

for(int i=0; i<events.length; i++)
  MainWebView.dispatchKeyEvent(events[i]); // MainWebView is webview
```

You can build the string[] szStringText with "!/§)". Normally, the code convert charactere. Source : https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/android.view.KeyCharacterMap

Comment: That's what I did but the characters I need are not part of the maps so there will be no result returned from getEvents. I had to use the local keymap with region specific characters. What I want is a way to insert characters without requiring a special keymap loaded.